# How to control the top command in Linux using a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Running top interactively you can do different things. Is there a way to write a bash script that would interact with top without using programs like xdotool?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly one can achieve with top, but I suspect that everything you can do with top interactively can also be solved with another non-interactive command. Example: you can kill a process in top, but you can achieve the same thing with `kill <pid>`

Comment: @Hasturkun I wanted to be able to go through different displays of the top command e.g. sorted by different criteria

Comment: @Misch Yes I realize that, thanks.

Comment: Did you try: `top -n1 -b`?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option, if you want to interact with `top` from a script, would be to have a script that runs it once and captures the output (`top -n1` will make it run once and then terminate). You can have your script run `top -n1` with appropriate other parameters every time it wants to capture new output, and control it accordingly.

Trying to run an interactive `top` session, and have a script send it keystrokes, would be very fragile and quite a mess.

Answer (score 0):

`top` isn't the best tool to run from scripts. Foremost, it's output isn't designed to be processed by scripts. But if you tell us what you want to achieve, then we can tell you commands that do similar things:

`ps` lists active processes. `iostat` gives you disk and other I/O data. `sar` reports system activity (network, interrupts, ...)

Comment: Yes I am using ps and will probably use iostat too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
top -b -n n1 -d d1
```

where,

```
n1 = duration for which top output to be collected (in seconds)
d1 = how often you need to collect top output (in milliseconds)
```

Example:

```
top -b -n $n1 -d $d1 | grep "Cpu" > top.txt (n1 and d1 accepted from user)
```